# Anylogic Parameter variation with single python run using the Python Communicator

Tags: genetic-algorithm, anylogic, vehicle-routing

I am using the python connector to call a genetic algorithm (GA) in python. The idea is to evaluate multiple vehicle routing solutions from the GA using a parameter variation. The python script is modelled in the main 'on start-up'. However, with a parameter variation, this implies that the entire python script is rerun. I can generate the solutions manually and insert them in Anylogic, but preferably this is directly performed via the python connector. I have tried it with a function also but there the same happens. Any advice on how I can ensure that the python script is called once and that a parameter variation uses these results? Is this even possible in Anylogic?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call your script as part of the experiment setup and then use that value for every simulation run.

[image]

Comment: I have found it, thanks. It is possible to add the python communicator to an experiment https://www.anylogic.com/upload/pdf/q-and-a-with-writeups.pdf)  However, this has to be done manually before the python communicator works properly.

Comment: Awesome. Feel free to answer your own question and accept it!